# Treeview in angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to get a tree view working in angular ui-grid.  However I always get the error that the template for the treeViewRowHeader cannot be found.

In the example there is no such template and no call is made to the server for this template.

Anyone know where/how i should specify this template?

BTW: Using RC21

Comment: Can you share your code. Otherwise its difficult to find where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, stupid mistake in using the wrong css file for angular grid.